# how to set the values of one array to another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying array by value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

I am a beginner with javascript, so I would really appreciate any help or advice. I'm trying to get the values that I collect with my inputs array (that are put into a form, by the user, in the document) to set them to the words array. So, I would like `inputs[0] = words[0]`, `inputs[1] = words[1]` etc. I thought by setting words to an empty array, and then to equal the index value of inputs, that I would achieve this, but it's not working. Words keeps showing up as "undefined".

```
function goMad() { 
    var words = [];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length - 1; i++) { 
        inputs[i].value = words;
    }

    var story = words[0] + "! he said " + words[1] + " as he jumped into his convertible " + words[2] + " and drove off with his " + words[3] + " wife.";
    document.getElementById("story").innerHTML = story;

    console.log(words[0]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want it the other way round - to set items in `words`, use `words[i] = inputs[i].value`.

Comment: It might help to understand that `=` is called an "Assignment Operator". You are assigning to the left side with the value of the right side.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this line:

```
inputs[i].value = words;
```

You can use:

```
words.push(inputs[i].value);
```

This will add the provided value to the `words` array. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

As **@pimvdb** and **@Shmiddty** have pointed out you could also use the following. This would behave exactly the same as using `push`:

```
words[i] = inputs[i].value;
```

Comment: Why you pass this in a function when you can just instanciate the array?

Comment: or `words[i] = inputs[i].value;`

Comment: @MikeBoutin `inputs` will be an array of DOM elements whereas `words` (I guess) is intended to be an array of `String`s.

Comment: @Shmiddty yep, equally valid.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think the response given by primvdb is originally what I was trying to go for, as I was trying to give words (which, yes, is an array of string values) to the same value as inputs. Seeing the push method used in this way was also very helpful as it seems to accomplish the same thing. Like I said, I am new at this. thanks!